# Sum Form Columns In Realtime

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Have a form where I input scores of a game for the home and away team. Am trying to have it automatically sum scores as each score type is entered for each team. Currently the code I have will only sum the score for Team 2 on the score for Team 1 as per the diagram below (I can't embed pictures yet).

```
                        Team 1                  Team 2
               Score       7                       0
Score Type 1 (5pts)        0                       1
Score Type 2 (2pts)        0                       1
```

Team 1 should sum to score for Team 1 and Team 2 should sum to score for Team 2, like this

```
                        Team 1                  Team 2
               Score       12                      7
Score Type 1 (5pts)        2                       1
Score Type 2 (2pts)        1                       1
```

I Can get it to successfully do the sum for the first column (home team) when entering the home teams scores however when I add in for the second I get the problem as described.

Below is the html for the form and input fields, I've removed code that doesn't relate to the problem at hand:

```
<form action='./includes/enterScore.php' method='post' class='formAddScore'>
  <div class='addScoreRow'>
    <div class='addScoreCountryCol'>&nbsp</div>
    <div class='addScoreCountryCol'><input type='number' disabled id='homeScore' min='0' placeholder='0'></input></div>
    <div class='addScoreCountryCol'><input type='number' disabled id='awayScore' min='0' placeholder='0'></input></div>
  </div>
  <div class='addScoreRow'>
    <div class='addScoreCountryCol'><span class='addScoreLabel'>".$score1plu.":</span></div>
    <div class='addScoreCountryCol'><label for='hscore1'><input type='number' id='hscore1' name='score1' min='0' value='0' size='3' class='addScoreInput'></label></div>
    <div class='addScoreCountryCol'><label for='ascore1'><input type='number' id='ascore1' name='score7' min='0' value='0' size='3' class='addScoreInput'></label></div>
    <input type='hidden' value=".$score1pnt." name='scorepnt1'>
  </div>
  <div class='addScoreRow'>
    <div class='addScoreCountryCol'><span class='addScoreLabel'>".$score2plu.":</span></div>
    <div class='addScoreCountryCol'><label for='hscore2'><input type='number' id='hscore2' name='score2' min='0' value='0' size='3' class='addScoreInput'></label></div>
    <div class='addScoreCountryCol'><label for='ascore2'><input type='number' id='ascore2' name='score8' min='0' value='0' size='3' class='addScoreInput'></label></div>
    <input type='hidden' value=".$score2pnt." name='scorepnt2'>
  </div>
  </div>
</form>";
```

Here is the javascript I'm using, suspect the correction I need to make is here but am unable to find out what I need to do to fix it:

```
  $('input').on('change', function() {
    var score1val = <?php echo $score1pnt ?>;
    var score2val = <?php echo $score2pnt ?>;
            
    var homescore = parseInt($('#hscore1').val() * score1val) + parseInt($('#hscore2').val() * score2val || '0')
    $('#homeScore').val(homescore);
    
    var awayscore = parseInt($('#ascore1').val() * score1val) + parseInt($('#ascore2').val() * score2val || '0')
    $('#homeScore').val(awayscore);
  })
</script>
```

Comment: where are put the value 5 and 2? i dont see these values in your code? or they are in hidden input?

Comment: Please don’t tag unrelated stuff (no AJAX involved in what you have shown), and please show _client-side_ code, if you want to discuss a client-side problem. (The HTML you have shown still contains PHP parts. Easier to reproduce your problem for everyone here, if we don’t have to supply values for PHP variables ourselves, but you showed the actual HTML this created in the first place.)

Comment: You are currently writing the result to `#homeScore` for _both_ values. `$('#homeScore').val(awayscore);` wants to be `$('#awayScore').val(awayscore);`

Comment: @CBroe, thankyou for the tips, my first question here so mucked it up a bit ... have removed the AJAX tag and will take your other advice on board for any future questions. Your second comment fixed the problem, thankyou for that, I'd pored over it for an hour but just couldn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

this code does the job, you have to  fix some errors (the result in same id):

I suggest you to select only the input not disabled to avoid to loop more times when the value changes

```
$('input[type=number]:not(:disabled)').on('change', function() {
  //you could trap the values from JS
  var score1val = parseInt($("input[name=scorepnt1]").val());
  var score2val = parseInt($("input[name=scorepnt2]").val());

  //you could keep the values given by PHP
  //var score1val = parseInt(<?php echo $score1pnt ?>);
  //var score2val = parseInt(<?php echo $score2pnt ?>);

  var homescore = parseInt($('#hscore1').val()) * score1val + parseInt($('#hscore2').val()) * score2val;
  $('#homeScore').val(homescore);

  var awayscore = parseInt($('#ascore1').val()) * score1val + parseInt($('#ascore2').val()) * score2val;   
  $('#awayScore').val(awayscore);
})
```

Comment: Hi Frenchy, CBroe's second comment above fixed my problem however if your suggestion is a better way of doing it I will give that a go as well.